# Yii Property "CListView.X" is not defined

Tags: php, yii

I am new at Yii and trying to show the list of user on the home page and while doing so I am getting error: Property "CListView.userlist" is not defined. Code:
SiteController.php

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    // This is the function which I changed reset is file remains same
    public function actionIndex() {
        $userlist = User::model()->findAllBySql($sql);
        $this->render('index',array('userlist'=>$userlist,));
    }
}
```

The code for view of the site, index.php:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'userlist'=>$userlist,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    ));
```

In last _view.php:

```
echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id'));
```

Currently in with code I am getting error: Property "CListView.userlist" is not defined. But if I replace $userlist with $dataProvider, the error changes to "Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in C:\devCenter\yii\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php on line 107"

I have two questions:

1. It seems there special meaning of $dataProvider, please me tell why is that.
2. I am passing $userlist from SiteController to index.php then to $this->widget(), but in _view.php the variable changes to $data, what am I missing?
   I have read through the documentation in Yii site yet I couldn't follow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done mistake in the syntax of ClistView that is in place of dataprovider you have inserted userlist and due to that you are getting the error `undefined userlist`

This is your syntax

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'userlist'=>$userlist,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    ));
```

The right syntax is as shown

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataprovider'=>$userlist,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    ));
```

And `$userlist` must be a valid dataprovider to define it properly follow the steps provided by Daniel Vaquero

Answer (score 1):

In SiteController:
**actionIndex()** function, the '**$sql**' is **not defined**...

**Edited:**

For CListView Widget, you need transform '$userlist' to 'CActiveDataProvider', like this:

```
$userlist = User::model()->findAllBySql($sql);
$userListDP = new CActiveDataProvider($userlist);
$this->render('index',array('userListDP'=>$userListDP));
```

In view file:
The CListView Widget needs a dataProvider.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$userListDP, // CListView collect the data from 'dataProvider' param name.
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    ));
```